# State resets when values change in an object, only when I populate from another source

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

What I'm trying to do is the following:

1. I want to select a single card view and edit it
2. After editing it, I would like to save the changes

Please look at video I've upload for reference and could please explain what's going on, why is this happening. Is there a better way to do this without writing t0o much code as the state has a huge variable list and writing each variable will be time consuming.

[image: Reference Video of bug]

This is my default `useState` where all values will be stored temporarily:

```js
  const [business, setBusiness] = useState<Partial<BusinessInterface>>({});
```

And the function to populate the state above is as follows:

```js
  const editHandler = async (e: any) => {
    let editBusiness = await businessArray.businesses?.find(x =>
      x.businessId?.equals(e),
    );

    console.log(e);

    if (editBusiness) {
      setBusiness(editBusiness);
      setEditBusiness(true);
      setModal(true);
    }
  }
```

However, the moment I start entering values, my state will clear the old state plus my change functions are all correct. please take a look at `registrationNumberHandler`

```js
  const registrationNumberHandler = (
    e: NativeSyntheticEvent<TextInputChangeEventData>,
  ) => {
    let value = e.nativeEvent.text;
    setBusiness({...business, registrationNumber: value});
  }
```

But however, when I change `editHandler` to as follows, it will work and my state will not change or clear the value when I edit a certain text field.

```js
  const editHandler = async (e: any) => {
    let editBusiness = await businessArray.businesses?.find(x =>
      x.businessId?.equals(e),
    );

    if (editBusiness) {
      setBusiness({...business, name: editBusiness.name, registrationNumber: editBusiness.registrationNumber); // a short example, when text fields changes state will retain its values
      setEditBusiness(true);
      setModal(true);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure in what scope your `business` variable is, but I think you're probably getting a stale state when you're trying to update it. You usually would want to use the callback version of the [setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) function.

```
   setBusiness((prevValues) => ({...prevValues, registrationNumber: value}));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let editBusiness = await businessArray.businesses?.find(x =>
      x.businessId?.equals(e),
    );

console.log(e);
if (editBusiness) {
   setBusiness(editBusiness);
```

Here you are passing editBusiness to setBusiness as a reference. So, editBusiness is also referring to the same object in businessArray. And now when you modify anything, it will modify the mainArray as well as both are pointing to the same memory location.

```
setBusiness({...business, name: editBusiness.name, registrationNumber: editBusiness.registrationNumber);
```

Here, instead of passing reference you have created a new object which is not pointing to your businessArray and hence it doesn't modify your previous state on edit.

Comment: so in other words, I will have to write all the variable I want to assign in `setBusiness({/**Variables*/)}`?

Comment: if its an object use spread operator and assign it to state.

Comment: please provide and example...

Comment: provide a minimal reproducible code in codesandox will make changes there.

Answer (score 0):

Your components are probably running with an outdated scope.
A component will only know about changes to `business` after it re-renders.

`await` pushes the execution of your code to the back of the queue which may cause the scope of your component to be even more outdated.

Solution: `setState` (or `setBusiness` in your case) has a way of giving you the most recent state.

Take a look at the rewritten function below. It should solve your problems

```
const registrationNumberHandler = (
    e: NativeSyntheticEvent<TextInputChangeEventData>
) => {
    let value = e.nativeEvent.text
    setBusiness(previousState => ({
        ...previousState,
        registrationNumber: value
    }))
}
```